# How to create a pan & zoom effect for an image with different proportions to its container?

Tags: javascript, image, math, frontend, zooming

I have the following simple code that pans and zooms an image (slightly modified from [here]:(https://www.cssscript.com/image-zoom-hover-effect/)

```
    function imageZoom(container, img) {

      container.addEventListener("mousemove", onZoom);
      container.addEventListener("mouseover", onZoom);
      container.addEventListener("mouseleave", offZoom);
      function onZoom(e) {
    
        let offset = container.getBoundingClientRect();
          const x = e.clientX - offset.left;
          const y = e.clientY - offset.top;
          img.style.transformOrigin = `${x}px ${y}px`;
          img.style.transform = "scale(2.5)";
      }
      function offZoom(e) {
          img.style.transformOrigin = `center center`;
          img.style.transform = "scale(1)";
      }
    }
```

This works well when the image is proportional to container. I need it to work with random-sized images inside square containers, with the ability to show the entire image via pan & zoom.

I've tried multiplying X and Y by

```
        let coefX= img.naturalWidth / container.offsetWidth
        let coefY= img.naturalHeight / container.offsetHeight
```

respectively, but that resulted in the image leaving the container altogether. I feel like the math is simple and obvious, but I can't seem to grasp it - other attempts I've made resulted in similar problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always wanted to make that effect. I "found" this [online](https://chat.openai.com/). This solution features only pan, no zoom. With an added bonus of a safe zone around the frame.

```js
// container, image are defined

function panImage(event) {

  // Adjust this value to control the buffer area around the frame
  const buffer = 10; 

  const containerRect = container.getBoundingClientRect();

  const mouseX = event.clientX - containerRect.left;
  const mouseY = event.clientY - containerRect.top;

  const maxX = image.clientWidth - container.clientWidth;
  const maxY = image.clientHeight - container.clientHeight;

  const xPercentage = (mouseX - buffer) / (container.clientWidth - buffer * 2);
  const yPercentage = (mouseY - buffer) / (container.clientHeight - buffer * 2);

  const offsetX = Math.min(Math.max(0, xPercentage * maxX), maxX);
  const offsetY = Math.min(Math.max(0, yPercentage * maxY), maxY);

  image.style.transform = `translate(-${offsetX}px, -${offsetY}px)`;
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#image {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" onmousemove="panImage(event)">
  <img id="image" src="https://picsum.photos/412/370">
</div>
```

Comment: This should work out of the box if I just replace the image with the zoomed in one, thanks!